# React conditional rendering with OR operator

Tags: reactjs, typescript, if-statement, conditional-rendering

Is it possible to write a conditional render with an OR operator in the statement? to avoid double code.

```
{regions && || regionsWithAnimals && (
  <>
    <h4>Title</h4>
    <div>
      <RegionsMap
        regions={regions || regionsWithAnimals.regions }
      />
    </div>
  </>
)}
```

Something like this, this is not working of course

EDIT: 
I could write:

```
{regions &&  (
  <>
    <h4>Title</h4>
    <div>
      <RegionsMap
        regions={regions }
      />
    </div>
  </>
)}
```

and below:

```
{regionsWithAnimals && (
  <>
    <h4>Title</h4>
    <div>
      <RegionsMap
        regions={regionsWithAnimals.regions }
      />
    </div>
  </>
)}
```

This is what I want to achieve, but I'm calling two times the same component.

Comment: What do you mean by "avoid double code"?

Comment: Do you mean ternary operator ? And please describe your problem with proper source code, its unclear.

Comment: I could write: 

```
{regions &&  (
  <>
    <h4>Title</h4>
    <div>
      <RegionsMap
        regions={regions }
      />
    </div>
  </>
)}
```

and below: 
```
{regionsWithAnimals && (
  <>
    <h4>Title</h4>
    <div>
      <RegionsMap
        regions={regionsWithAnimals }
      />
    </div>
  </>
)}
```

This is what I want to achieve, but I'm calling two times the same component.

Comment: `(regions || regionsWithAnimals) && ...` Though I should point out in your example if both are true they each render, but what you describe you want is for one or the other to render. Just keep the conditions in the same order in the component.

Comment: I'm sorry guys, the comment don't format. I updated the startpost with the code I want to achieve.

@DrewReese If I do that, it will give me the error `Type '{ name: string; path: string; }[] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'regions'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '{ name: string; path: string; }[]'.` 

By defining the props 'regions'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
{(regions || regionsWithAnimals && regionsWithAnimals.regions) && (
  <>
    <h4>Title</h4>
    <div>
      <RegionsMap
        regions={regions || regionsWithAnimals.regions  }
       />
    </div>
  </>
)}
```

Comment: Object is possibly undefined if do that

Comment: What "Object' ?

Comment: `<RegionsMap
        regions={regions || regionsWithAnimals.regions }
       />`

I'm sorry, I missed some code. regionsWithAnimals.regions is possibly undefined. And if I write the following code: 

`regions={RegionsPerCountry || isRegion?.regions}` it will give the following error: `Type '{ name: string; path: string; }[] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'regions'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '{ name: string; path: string; }[]'.`

Comment: I updated the Answer, you check also for regionsWithAnimals && regionsWithAnimals.regions

Comment: Still object is possibly undefined after your updated answer

Comment: So the problem is not with the conditional rendering

Comment: You're right! It is a TypeScript types problem now. I added undefined as option to the type, not sure if this is what I want but it works for now. 

`type regions = {
    name: string,
    animal: string;
}[] | undefined;`